# How to figure out what Javascript methods/features/etc are available in ECMAscript 3.0

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-3

Hey I have an interesting question, I work with a platform that uses server-side javascript, but unfortunately this platform only supports ECMAscript 3.0. What's the easiest way for me to tell what arrays/methods are available for me to use within thi version?

I know some of the obvious things (i.e. arrow functions and most array methods), but i've definitely spent hours over code, wondering why it wasn't working in this platform, to figure out it's because i'm using an unsupported method.

Comment: How about reading the ECMAScript 3 specification? It's available online.

Comment: How did you determine it only supports up to ECMAscript 3.0. version ?

Answer (score 1):

MDN links are broken, ECMA official website seem to have the archives. Please check this pdf.
https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_3rd_edition_december_1999.pdf

Online archives for all historical versions are available at this link
https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code with the most recent ES features and then use babel to transpile it to ES 3 before pushing to production. That's much easier than figuring out what you can use on ES 3.
I think there's a VS Code extension that simplifies the use of babel (similarly to what Live SASS Compiler does to convert SASS to CSS)